# select column1 from table A based on unique value of another column2 in table B

Tags: sql

I have table A and table B and need to select a column1 from table A based on unique value of another column in table B

**table A**

```
id | product |          
1  |  A      |        
1  |  B      |        
1  |  A      |          
2  |  A      |     
3  |  B      |          
4  |  A      |
```

**table B**

```
id | product | date     
1  |  A      | 1/01/2017                                                            
1  |  B      | 1/02/2017    
1  |  A      | 1/01/2017    
2  |  A      | 1/01/2017    
3  |  B      | 1/02/2017    
4  |  A      | 1/01/2017
```

I want the output to be : `2,3,4`

i.e. all the 'id's' which have a unique value in 'date' column of table B

Comment: You've tagged `sql` - which engine specifically? MySQL? SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the actual restrictions in your tables, there are a couple of options.

Option 1 - assuming that for example ID=1, Product=A, date=1/01/2017 and ID=1, Product=B, date=1/01/2017 means that ID=1 **IS NOT** included in your final result as it has 2 entries for the date = 1/01/2017 even though they are for different Products

```
SELECT a.ID
FROM
(
   SELECT ID, COUNT(*)
   FROM TableB
   GROUP BY ID
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) a
```

Option 2 - assuming that for example ID=1, Product=A, date=1/01/2017 and ID=1, Product=B, date=1/01/2017 means that ID=1 **IS** included in your final result as it only has a single date for each ID/Product combination

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM
( 
   SELECT ID, Product, COUNT(*)
   FROM TableB
   GROUP BY ID, Product
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) a
```

Comment: option 1 is the result I am looking for. What is 'a' in this query?

Comment: "a" is just an alias for the subquery. It is required to satisfy the T-SQL syntax.